# Django get a more specific hour range data

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Record_Date=models.DateTimeField()
```

In views.py

```
"""Takes an integer value representing the day of week from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)."""

    People.objects.filter(Record_Date__week_day=1)
```

It gives me all Sunday Record_Date's. That is fine. But, I want to get a more specific hour inside each Sunday data. For example, Every Sunday 10:30-11:55. How can I do that with using query or What is other alternatives to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can always just take the results out and filter in python.

```
results = People.objects.filter(Record_Date__week_day=1)
filtered = [r for r in results if 55 <= r.Record_Date.minute <= 30 and 10 <= r.Record_Date.hour <= 11]
```

And split out into a loop for easier debug:

```
results = People.objects.filter(Record_Date__week_day=1)
filtered = []
for r in results:
    print r.Record_Date
    if 55 <= r.Record_Date.minute <= 30:
        print r.Record_Date.minute, r.Record_Date.hour
        if 10 <= r.Record_Date.hour <= 11:
            print "Found!"
            filtered.append(r)
```

Comment: It does not work. Error says: Join on field 'Record_Date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'minute' for the lookup type?

Comment: I think lookups  only for year, month and day, Right?

Comment: join error... hmmm... ok this may not work.  How about if you try multiple filters.

Comment: no you have a DateTimeField, I think that lookup should work.

Comment: I think they are same, and the problem is 'Record_Date__hour__gte' See:http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year

Comment: oops forgot the field name... also it's django convention to use lowercase field names btw.

Comment: it does not return anything, Why ?

Comment: you have to take a look at your data to see if there should be any results.

Comment: I am sure I have, and control from my database.

Comment: it returns like that [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ] how can I access dates in 'filtered' ?

Comment: lists are accessed by index, first = filtered[0].  It seems likely that you may have defined a \_\_unicode\_\_ method on your model that's returning "".

Comment: when I print 'first' , it prints 'People object' ?

Comment: Ok, What about Sunday 10:50-12:25... How to do that ?

Comment: take I look at the loop above, I have faith that you can figure out how to modify it as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, I prefer to do in database level, It will be much better. First, do you have any idea to do with a query. Second, question is how to differentiate one week data from the other week ?

Comment: I've posted one solution, which will work, but if you want you can always write the raw SQL and do your query in the DB.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/

Comment: as to the second question, if you are querying for only for a single day of the week, i.e. Sunday, then you can use the fields "day" attribute to differentiate weeks.